# Turkey Continues on Daylight Saving Time From 2016 - Impact on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timezone, dst

what is impact on Postgresql databases? Jobs ,date columns datas will be affected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 2):

postgresql uses the [zoneinfo database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for time zone computations. The database's 2016g version which was released 2 weeks ago, [includes an update](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2016g/NEWS) to handle the situation for Turkey correctly. For now, you'll have to wait for the postgresql developers to pull the latest version of zoneinfo into postgresql and then release a new version. You can check what postgres thinks for Turkey's timezone as follows:

```
$ SET TIME ZONE 'Asia/Istanbul';
$ SELECT extract(timezone FROM '2016-06-01'::timestamptz), extract(timezone FROM '2016-12-01'::timestamptz);
 date_part | date_part 
-----------+-----------
     10800 |      7200
(1 row)
```

As you can see, on my system (postgresql 9.5.4), it still thinks that Turkey will switch to +2 offset in the winter.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as this change hits the [IANA timezone library](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), it will be included in PostgreSQL with the next [minor release](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). This has happened with commit [a03339aef2](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=a03339aef2b8b5e8379a9550b8ce2add5b436e9f), so the change will be in 9.6.1, 9.5.5, 9.4.10, 9.3.15, 9.2.19 and 9.1.24.

Data of type `timestamp with time zone` will not be affected, as they are stored in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) internally. If your client time zone is set to `Turkey` or equivalent, the data will be displayed with the (new) correct time zone offset.

Data of type `timestamp without time zone` will stay the same, so they will not be automatically shifted to the new time zone offset upon display. But it's almost always a mistake to use that data type anyway.