# MySQL - Turkey/Istanbul Daylight Saving Time Change

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, timezone, amazon-rds

Until this year Turkey was using daylight saving time, staying UTC+2 on winter period, UTC+3 on summer. This year it is decided to stay only in UTC+3.

Our DateTime's are persisted on MySQL (5.26.34) db (on AWS) was using UTC timezone.

- When i try to use CONVERT_TZ(DateTime, UTC, EUROPE/ISTANBUL) for recent datetime -lets say- 2016-11-21 00:00 it tries to convert according to UTC+2, whereas it suppose to be UTC+3.
- When i would tried to convert 2015-11-21 00:00 -last year- it converts correctly since Turkey was in UTC+2 at that time.

I Found an announcement on AWS forum[1], advicing to use Moscow timezone, which is not an option for us since Turkey's timezone situation is unique and our DateTime's are saved in the form of UTC0.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=4115

same question for posgresql: [Turkey Continues on Daylight Saving Time From 2016 - Impact on Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700628/turkey-continues-on-daylight-saving-time-from-2016-impact-on-postgresql)

Comment: [Staying Current with Time Zone Changes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-upgrades.html)

Comment: Did your operating system ship a time-zone file update?

Comment: @tadman well, i am using on AWS RDS, and updated the mysql latest version of mysql 5.6.

Comment: Did you [update the time-zone files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html)? This requires an operating-system level update first. It's possible that Amazon's image does not include that patch.

Comment: @tadman how can i perform operating-system level update on aws rds? i cannot i guess.

Comment: Right, you can't -- RDS doesn't give you OS access; however, it *should* be possible to solve this a different way.  I will verify my proposed solution and then post an answer if it is viable.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks, as a final solution i'll create custom convert_tz function. (we are using convert_tz in all our apps)